# sed command - regex and row count

Tags: regex, sed

I have file with contents like:

```
E error1
error1.2
error1.3
error1.4
error1.5

E error2
error2.2
error2.3
error2.4
error2.5

E error1
error1.2
error1.3
error1.4
error1.5

S not error
```

I want to return anything that matches 'E error' plus the 4 lines after it. I can do with 'sed' for first occurance:

```
sed -n '/E/,5p'
```

but this only returns 5 lines of the first occurance of 'E error'. I need it for all occurances
I also want to dedupe then count the total of each type and print the number of occurances of say 'E error1' underneath the 5 rows returns.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Can't you use `grep`, or it is necessary to use `sed`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` and its `-A` (after) option:

```
grep -A4 'E error' file
```

To get the countof each type, you can

```
grep 'E error' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: but it displays `--` for the blank lines.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: If you want blank lines instead, you can add `sed 's/^--$//'`

Comment: no, it must be `grep -A4 'E error' file | sed '/^--$/d'` . Removing will results in a blank line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` for you that will get the next four line after hit of pattern:

```
awk '/E error/{_=5}_-->0' file
E error1
error1.2
error1.3
error1.4
error1.5
E error2
error2.2
error2.3
error2.4
error2.5
E error1
error1.2
error1.3
error1.4
error1.5
```

Or you can use this:

```
awk '/E error/{_=5}_&&_--' file
```

PS, `_` is just used for fun, but is like any `awk` variable name. To make it more readable:

```
awk '/E error/{c=5} c && c--' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/E error/,+4p' inputFile
```

gives output as

```
E error1
error1.2
error1.3
error1.4
error1.5
E error2
error2.2
error2.3
error2.4
error2.5
E error1
error1.2
error1.3
error1.4
error1.5
```

**What it does?**

`-n` suppreses automatic printing of pattern space

`'/E/,+4` matches lines from occurence of `E` and `4` lines following it

`p` prints the current pattern space

Comment: Should be `sed -n '/E error/,+4p'` since OP says `anything that matches 'E error' plus` (cosmetics, but..)

Comment: @Jotne will make it more specific. edited the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has a blank line between records so just set the awk Record Separator to match and all you need is:

```
awk -v RS= '/^E error/' file
```